# Function does not continue after catch

Tags: flutter, dart, http

I have a `try..catch` within a dart function. When the `await client.post` throws an error, it does not continue after the catch, why?

```
  @override
  Future<http.Response> post(url, {Map<String, String?>? headers, body, Encoding? encoding, BuildContext? context}) async {
    headers = await prepareHeaders(headers);

    http.Response? response = null;
    try {
      response = await client.post(url, headers: headers as Map<String, String>?, body: body, encoding: encoding);
    } catch (_) {
      debugPrint('test'); // It comes here        
    }
    // Does not come here

   log(url: url, type: 'POST', body: body as String?, response: response!);
   return await parse(response, context: context);
  }
```

Comment: could you include log function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code almost certainly *is* continuing after the `catch` block; it's just immediately throwing another exception.  If `client.post` throws an exception, then `response` will not be set and will retain its initial value of `null`.  However, after your `catch` block, you do:

```dart
log(url: url, type: 'POST', body: body as String?, response: response!);
```

which asserts that `response` is not `null`.  That will throw a `TypeError`.

I don't know why you aren't observing the `TypeError`, but I'd suspect that you have a blanket `catch` block somewhere higher up in the call stack that is swallowing the exception (especially given your use of `catch (_)` in what code you have shown).  This is why Effective Dart recommends:

- [Avoiding `catch` without `on`](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/usage#avoid-catches-without-on-clauses).
- [Not catching `Error`s](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/usage#avoid-catches-without-on-clauses).

Comment: Android studio did not catch the TypeError, when I selected "Stop on all Exceptions" in the Flutter dev tools the breakpoint got hit

Answer (score 2):

And it shouldnt. In the code below the catch, you are relying on the response object being set. If the post errors, that wont be the case, producing more errors. Move the log and the return call inside the try block.

Answer (score 1):

The function will not execute after the `catch` block, the function will be terminated after the `catch` whenever any exception occurred then the `catch` block gets called. To solve this issue you can try this.

```
@override
Future<http.Response> post(url, {Map<String, String?>? headers, body, 
Encoding? encoding, BuildContext? context}) async {
headers = await prepareHeaders(headers);

http.Response? response = null;
try {
  response = await client.post(url, headers: headers as Map<String, 
  String>?, body: body, encoding: encoding);
log(url: url, type: 'POST', body: body as String?, response: response!);
return await parse(response, context: context);
 } catch (_) {
  debugPrint('test');
  rethrow;
  }
}
```

Comment: Is that how the try catch works in Dart that it returns from the function "automatically", or is it because I rely on the response later on in the function?

Comment: Suppose you are getting a `success` response which a status code of `200` then you can return from the try block and if that execution failed which a status code like `400` or `403` then the `catch` block gets called you can `return` exception also. That is how it is work

Comment: "the function will be terminated after the catch whenever any exception occurred then the catch block gets called." That's not true.  If you want a function to not resume execution after a `catch` block, that `catch` block would need to `return` or `throw`.